# Recursion formula for odd holonomic function

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $E$ be the space of maps 
$f:\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}[t^{\pm}]$
satisfying $\forall i$, $f(i)=-f(-i)$.

The algebra 
$$\mathcal{T}=\mathbb{C}[t^{\pm}]\langle L^{\pm},M^{\pm}\rangle/(LM-tML)$$ acts on $E$ by
$$(Lf)(i)=f(i+1),\quad (Mf)(i)=t^if(i).$$

Is the annihilating ideal of $f\in E$ generated by annihilators in the symmetric part of $\mathcal{T}$?

Symmetric part means the subset with all element like $aL^xM^y+aL^{-x}M^{-y}$ and their multiplication or linear combination.

Comment: Is this question too hard?

I do not have any good idea yet.

Comment: The question is incomprehensible. Do you mean "Is" instead of "Should"? What does ${\bf C}[t^{\pm}]$ mean?

Comment: OP seems to have abandoned this question. Voting to close. 

Comment: C[t^{\pm}] means the Laurant Polynomials of t